# Determine the IP address of the DHCP server from a client machine

Tags: linux, centos, dhcp, linux-networking, dhcp-server

I would like to know what is the best way to get the DHCP server address from a client (**linux based**), who just got an IP address from the DHCP server?

I searched and found this in most of the articles,

```
less /var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases
```

But say, the client is a Virtual machine and was assigned an IP address from some external DHCP server, then the file '/var/lib/dhcp3/dhclient.leases' won't be present.

I've tried doing a 'ifconfig' in the client machine and this was the output

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0C:29:2C:3C:6A  
          inet addr:192.168.163.128  Bcast:192.168.163.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I can see the BroadCast(Bcast) address but cannot find anywhere the real DHCP server address.

Hope somebody could provide me a good solution.

Thanks and best regards.

Comment: Why do you believe `dhclient.leases` would not be present?  That doesn't make sense.  DHCP needs to store its state somewhere, and that is the place it is stored.  Why would being a virtual machine make one bit of difference.  The point of a VM is that the OS acts exactly like it would act on physical hardware.

Comment: Sorry to reply late. I was buried in some work. Yeah, I confirmed. When I got IP addresses from the external DHCP for my VM, say, when I'm in NAT mode in VMware, the dhclient.leases file wan't present. I don't know what might have happened.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Type `dhclient -v` 
In the out put search for DHCPACK. It has the IP of the dhcp server

Comment: I tried dhclient -v, it says "dhclient(31917) is already running - exiting."

Comment: Try `grep -r "DHCPOFFER" /var/log/* ` it will give you the dhcp server if you cannot run dhclient.

Comment: X Don't run this -> Downvoted - This command actually runs another dhclient process and now you have a possible outage for the server because the default route is messed up.

Comment: Yes, this creates a new dhclient process. Method suggested by @ManulaWaidyanatha works. May be that should be updated as an answer.